# jQuery not first selector found by attributeContains

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with selecting "not first selector" using `attributeContains`

```
jQuery('div[id*="abc"]:not(:first)').hide();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to chain it like this:

```
jQuery('div[id*="abc"]').not(':first').hide();
```

Comment: Thank you, but you have one ")" more, so correct is:

jQuery('div[id*="abc"]').not(':first').hide();